# Multiplying series and Binomial coefficient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I shall multiply two series and the result should then be in terms of a binomial coefficient. On the web I found this 'rule':

$$ \Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \frac{t^k}{k!}\Bigg) * \Bigg(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j \frac{t^j}{j!} \Bigg)  = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \Bigg[ \sum_{i=0}^r \binom {r} {i} a_i b_{r-i} \Bigg] \frac{t^r}{r!}$$

I don't understand how to establish this result, can anybody help me?

Comment: Just expand and identify the coefficient of $t^r$ in the product.

Comment: See [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication of series can be visualized as follows :
$$
\eqalign{
&(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots)\cdot (b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+\cdots) = \cr
& a_0b_0 + \cr
& (a_0b_1 + a_1b_0)x + \cr
& (a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0)x^2 + \cr
& (a_0b_3 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 + a_3b_0)x^3 + \cr
& \cdots \cr
& \biggl(\sum_{i=0}^{r} a_ib_{r-i} \biggr)x^r \cr
& \cdots \cr
}
$$
In your case the coefficient of $t^r$ is :
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{r} {a_i\over i!}{b_{r-i}\over (r-i)!} = \sum_{i=0}^{r} {r! \over i!(r-i)!}{a_ib_{r-i}\over r!} = \sum_{i=0}^{r}\binom{r}{i}{a_ib_{r-i}\over r!}
$$